# tmux copy mode search for a Unicode string

Tags: unicode, tmux

In `tmux`'s copy mode, I cannot search for a Unicode (non-ASCII) string, `tmux` just doesn't show (and just ignore) non-ASCII characters in the "Search Up:" prompt!

In `~/.tmux.conf`, I have:

```
setw -g utf8 on
set -g status-utf8 on
set -g mouse-utf8 on
...
```

And I use

```
tmux -u
```

to start `tmux` (version 1.6) in `xterm`. (I've also tried this in `urxvt` and got same result.)

Any suggestions? Is searching with Unicode string supported? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like only non-control ASCII is currently accepted.

See the [MODEKEY_OTHER handling in `window_copy_key_input()` of `window-copy.c`](http://tmux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux/trunk/window-copy.c?revision=2745&view=markup#l783).

---

The underlying comparison code ([`window_copy_search_compare()`](http://tmux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux/trunk/window-copy.c?revision=2745&view=markup#l909)) looks like it handles UTF-8 mode, so you might be able to get some basic functionality by simply allowing bytes greater than 127 to be added to the buffer. There are (at least!<sup>†</sup>) some small problems if you do this though:

- Backspace still deletes one byte at a time. This can leave partial UTF-8 sequences in the buffer which seem to confuse the UTF-8 comparator (the resulting buffer matches everywhere!).
- Combining characters are not handled specially.
  As an example, the codepoint sequences U+00E9 and U+0065 U+0301 both look the same, but will compare as different (though each does compare as equal to itself).

You might want to ask on the [tmux-users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/tmux-users) for better-founded advice.

---

<sup>†</sup> There could also be large problems (e.g. crashing and killing all your sessions); I do not know the code well enough to guess.